# mutt: Decode quoted-printable encoded author name

Tags: mutt

I have to deal with several mails having a quoted-printable encoded From field like this one:

```
From: =?UTF-8?Q?=22Foo_Bar=22?= <foo@bar.com>
```

The `=22` result in `"` in mutt's index which looks ugly because messages with not quoted-printable encoded headers on the contrary get their quotation marks stripped.

Also when replying to such a mail, mutt will put the following in the To field:

```
To: "\"Foo Bar\"" <foo@bar.com>
```

Only in the pager view the headers are shown with stripped quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Mutt behaves correctly when replying, but is incorrect when stripping the quotation marks in the pager view (note: in the index view, the quotation marks are not stripped). Indeed, according to [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047), an encoded-word such as `=?UTF-8?Q?=22Foo_Bar=22?=` is used in place of an *atom*. So, the encoded quotes here are not used as part of the message syntax, but as part of the contents; thus they should not be stripped. In short:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?=22Foo_Bar=22?=
```

should give:

```
"Foo Bar"
```

and

```
=?UTF-8?Q?Foo_Bar?=
```

should give:

```
Foo Bar
```

When replying, the use of `\"` is a way to regard a quote as part of the contents (it's better than using RFC 2047 encoding for the text shown to the user). How it will be encoded internally (in the message format) is another matter.